# How can I throttle down Dropbox's IO operations?

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, priority, multitasking

Empirical evidence suggests that Dropbox's indexing at startup time is the main source of slowdown for my Windows 7 partition -- things grind down to a crawl when the indexing is in progress and resume to normal after this step is done and the dropbox icon turns to a green checkmark.

How can I make the initial Dropbox indexing more multitasking friendly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three options:

- Let Dropbox index less stuff.
- Use http://soluto.com/ to delay the start-up of Dropbox so it indexes at a more idle moment.
- Use Dropbox on demand rather than at boot.